# How to get grouped data as well as all data using mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the following code, I do get totalAccount and totalBalance. But, no other field/data is showing up. How can I also get all data from my collection that matches my query (brcode)?

```
const test = await db.collection('alldeposit').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                brcode: brcode
               
            }
        },
        
        {
           $group: {
               _id: null,
               totalAccount: {
                   $sum: 1
               },
               totalBalance: {
                   $sum: "$acbal"
               }
           }
        }
        
    ]).toArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify which fields you want to see in the `$group` stage

For example:

```
    await db.collection('alldeposit').aggregate([
       {
           $match: {
               brcode: brcode
           }
       },
      {
      $group: {
         _id : null,
         name : { $first: '$name' },
         age : { $first: '$age' },
         sex : { $first: '$sex' },
         province : { $first: '$province' },
         city : { $first: '$city' },
         area : { $first: '$area' },
         address : { $first: '$address' },
         totalAccount: {
             $sum: 1
         },
         totalBalance: {
            $sum: "$acbal"
         }
      }
    }]);
```

Edit:

Regarding our chat in the comments, unfortunately I don't know a way to do the operation you asked in a single aggregation.

But with two steps, you can do it:

First step:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
         brcode: brcode
      }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      totalAccount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalBalance: {
        $sum: "$acbal"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And second step:

```
db.collection.update(
  { brcode: brcode }
  ,{$set : {
     "totalAccount": totalAccount,
     "totalBalance": totalBalance
   }}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code. It's showing just one record. But, I have hundreds of records. How can I get all the records from my collection?

Comment: But the logic behind the `$group` is showing grouped data in a single document. If you want to show everything in the result, you have to use `$project` stage not `$group` if do you need help, I can give an example in the my answer.

Comment: Because I already have totalAccount and totalBalance in an Array [{ }], for all the other records, it would be great if I could get all the records this way => [{totalAccount and totalBalance}, {all other data from collection}]

Comment: Yes, project is an option. But, is it possible to get totalAccount , totalBalance and also all data from collection using a single mongodb aggregation (or any other way) ?

Comment: Okay, got it. I'll update my answer when I got time.

Comment: Thanks. I will highly appreciate that.

Comment: I tried your edited code. I'm afraid this does not work. But, yes, in two steps (with two aggregations) I can achieve what I want. Thanks.